# Case statement issues with ruby

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

I'm working on a tic-tac-toe problem for a ruby project. I'd like to have one method control and report who is the current player. For move zero I'd like to randomly pick who goes. After that it will alternate between the two players evenly. Here is my code so far

```
def current_player (move_counter = 0)
  case move_counter
  when move_counter = 0 
    player_on_deck = rand() > 0.5 ? "Computer" : @player
  when move_counter > 0
    player_on_deck == "Computer" ? @player : "Computer"
  end

  move_counter +=1 
  return player_on_deck move_counter
end
```

I think I'm messing up the implementation the `move_counter` to give me a switch for when to do what. Every time this method is called it starts from zero. Do i need to make a new method that only tracks moves and pass that value into this method? Or is there away to make `move_counter` stay up to date inside of this method?

Comment: There's no point in your case statement having the argument `move_counter` since both `when`'s are followed by a logical expression.  I noticed both answers appearing at this time also have `case move_counter`.  Since `move_counter` is always non-negative, you might just have `if move_counter == 0 ... else ... end`, rather than a case statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the value of `move_counter` in the `when` clause: `when move_counter = 0` should be `when move_counter == 0`.  Also, you have the reverse problem when trying to define `player_on_deck` for the second time -- you are using `==` but should be using `=`.

Here's what I think you are really trying to do:

```
def current_player (move_counter = 0)
  case move_counter
  when move_counter == 0 
    player_on_deck = rand() > 0.5 ? "Computer" : @player
  when move_counter > 0
    player_on_deck = "Computer" ? @player : "Computer"
  end

  return player_on_deck
end
```

Comment: `move_counter += 1` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to decide between passing the count as an argument and incrementing it inside the method (which isn't the best)

Try something like this:

```
def current_player (move_counter = 0)
  case move_counter
  when move_counter == 0 
    player_on_deck = rand() > 0.5 ? "Computer" : @player
  when move_counter > 0
    player_on_deck == "Computer" ? @player : "Computer"
  end

  return player_on_deck
end
```

and increment the `move_counter` at the bottom of your game loop.

the first time is taken care of via the default argument, and anytime past that will be dealt with by the counter you define at the bottom of your game loop.

**also as eebbesen has said, the move counter isn't being evaluated in your case statement, it's being reset.

Comment: Agreed— a method that returns the current player shouldn't be changing the current turn as well.

Comment: I think you're right. When i try either of the solutions i end up with something undefined. Either the player_on_deck is an undefined method, not sure why it's being taken as a method, or it throws the wrong number of args even with the move_counter having a default value... I should rethink this...

Comment: @AdamD.Bell it raises an undefined method because your line `return player_on_deck move_counter` reads as `return player_on_deck(move_counter)`. Maybe you could return an array: `return [player_on_deck, move_counter]`.